# Replace only one capture in a regex

Tags: regex, rust, replace

I have to replace certain parts in a text file but do not exactly how to manage this.
Given the text:

> ```
> Hello adorable world!
> Hello fantastic world!
> Hello my miserable world!
> Goodbye my adorable world!
> Goodbye my fantastic world!
> Goodbye my miserable world!
> ```

Now I am searching for the word following the "Hello my" and have to replace it by the next word in a given list - let's take "crucial" here

```
let mut my_text = "... see above";
let my_reg = Regex::new(r"Hello my (\S+) world!").unwrap();
let caps = my_reg.captures(&my_text).unwrap();
my_text = my_reg.replace(&my_text, "crucial".to_string()).to_string();
```

but this will - not unexpected - replace "Hello my miserable world!" completely with "crucial"

What do I have to do to replace only the caps.get(1) - which here is the word "miserable"?

Comment: Just `my_reg.replace(&my_text, "Hello my crucial world!")`?

Comment: What would that do? I know that this is wrong, but all replacement examples I found do replace the complete regex and not just one part of it.

Comment: It will replace e.g. "Hello my miserable world!" with "Hello my crucial world!", of course. You could use lookaheads for that, but Rust's regex does not support them.

Comment: Or use `r"(Hello my )(\S+)( world!)"` and `my_reg.replace(&my_text, "${1}crucial${3}")` if the prefix and suffix aren't constant.

Comment: Sorry to Chayim - I did not read correct. The problem is, that I do not know the exact string before miserable and after, because this is found by a complex regex, too.

Comment: thanks to Jmb, this solves it - at least as it seems at the moment

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered, `Regex::replace` replaces the entire match. You can however, include parts of the match in the replacement.

To do that, you need to switch around which parts of the expression are capturing, so you can refer to the parts you want to *keep* instead of the parts you want to throw away:

```
let my_text = "Hello my miserable world!".to_string();
let my_reg = Regex::new(r"(Hello my) \S+ (world!)").unwrap();
let caps = my_reg.captures(&my_text).unwrap();
let my_text = my_reg.replace(&my_text, "$1 crucial $2".to_string()).to_string();
println!(my_text); // "Hello my crucial world!"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I got this sorted out in the mean time. In the real project (this is only an simplified example :-)) I mixed up two problems
this one and 
searching for a version number:
the version can be either like "V 1.2" or like "V1.2.3.4"

Comment: and each partnumber can have up to 3 digits. I tried this regex: r"V\s{0,1}(\d{1,3}\.{0,1}){1,4}". by now I have learned that nested capture groups are not a good idea in any given environment. So I regard this question as answered.